# CSS className not reflecting when using CSS Modules in my React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

This is the module section of my webpack.config.js file

```js
  module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            // loader: 'babel',
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         },
         {
           test: /\.css$/,
           loader:'style-loader!css-loader'
         }
      ]
   }
```

I have also installed css-loader and style-loader, this is how the package.json file looks -

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3"
}
```

This is my react component where I am trying to implement the CSS -

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Foodrecipe.css";

export default class Foodrecipe extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className={styles.recipe}>
            <h1>Healthy Main Dish Recipes</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

The CSS recipe class in Foodrecipe.css file is quite simple, its just -

```css
.recipe{
  background-color: yellow;
  color: blue;
}
```

But for some reason, the CSS change is not reflecting in the UI.

One more thing I would like to point out is when I am adding the attribute id to the div and naming it recipeDiv, and declaring the style of the id in the CSS -

```css
#recipeDiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: blue;
}
```

the changes are reflecting in the UI. So I am pretty sure that the CSS file is getting imported correctly here but there seems to be some issue with className attribute. That's what I think. Can anyone guide me here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am new to React and I am trying to implement CSS Modules with React and Webpack. One of the advantage of CSS Modules is, it allow us to write scoped CSS. We can write CSS for a component and be certain that it won’t leak into other components.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, I updated my question headline. So that in future people facing this issue can exactly know that this question is all about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution 1

You are trying to import `css` file as `styles` without using CSS Modules. Check **Solution 2** if you want to do it like that.

So just like you do in vanilla HTML & CSS, just give a `class` whose css property you want to use & make sure you just import it like `import './Foodrecipe.css'`.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Foodrecipe.css";

export default class Foodrecipe extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="recipe">
            <h1>Healthy Main Dish Recipes</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

## Solution 2

Use `query: { modules: true }` in `css-loader` to use it as CSS Modules, i.e, named import for a css file like `import styles from './FoodRecipe.css'`

### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Foodrecipe.css";

export default class Foodrecipe extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className={styles.recipe}>
            <h1>Healthy Main Dish Recipes</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/test.js"],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "engine.js"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015", "stage-2"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "css-loader",
        query: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: But the examples which I went through are doing it the same way, they are importing the file as styles. Why is it working for them and not for me? This is one of those examples: https://javascriptplayground.com/css-modules-webpack-react/

Comment: @Rito your modules config its not the same as its in the article

Comment: you need to use css-modules for that. Checkout https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10 for more info. Note you only need {modules:true} in css-loader config for that to work. Not sure though as I never did that.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 you are right, the missing piece was {modules: true}. This is the change I did in the webpack config file and it worked for me. Thanks a lot. Can you update your answer with this info, so that I can approve it.

Comment: {
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style-loader'
}, {
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'css-loader',
  query: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  }
}

Comment: I updated my webpack config file with the above code.

Comment: Does this do the scoping that Rito mentioned? E.g. if another module also uses the `recipe` class but for a different purpose, will this adequately isolate them?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder other than the article link that I shared above, you can also check this article, it also says the same thing. https://www.javascriptstuff.com/css-modules-by-example/#example-1-single-class-name

Comment: @Rito: Cool. And it makes sense as a direction forward, since the names have to be rewritten to avoid conflicts. So you *wouldn't* want `className="recipe"` as in the answer above.

Comment: @Rito Updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

Try importing the styles then apply them to the `div` with `className="recipe"` intead of: `className={styles.recipe}`

Do this:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Foodrecipe.css";

export default class Foodrecipe extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="recipe">
            <h1>Healthy Main Dish Recipes</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Why? What did you change? Why did you change it? How does that address what the OP is trying to achieve? Code dumps are not **useful** answers.

Comment: Look carefully.

Comment: You're completely missing the point. "Do this:" isn't an answer. At least you've now added some minimal explanation with an edit. It's not at all clear, though, that the OP isn't trying to do something more involved, though.