# How to Write Modifiers using Sass and BEM

Tags: css, sass, bem

I'm really confused with how to use scope with Sass and BEM convention.

I have the following code:

```
<div className="page">
   <div className="page__main-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a condition that sometimes will convert the following code above to:

```
   <div className="page">
       <div className="page__main-content main-content--active">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to represent that in sass I did the following:

```
.page{
  &__main-content{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100% - 20em);
    margin-left: 10.9em;
    &--active {
      width: calc(100% - 5em);
    }
  }
}
```

But the width does not change. Looking at the transpiled code it looks like this:

```
page__main-content main-content--active
```

How would I show this in Sass?

I also want to override the width (at both active and inactive state to this)

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .page{
    &__main-content {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks all right in https://www.sassmeister.com. Are you compiling sass or scss?

Comment: The sass you have in the first block compiles to `.page__main-content--active`. You need to set up a new rule for `main-content--active` like `.main-content { &--active {}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you should set it up in SASS:

```
.page{
  &__main-content{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100% - 20em);
    margin-left: 10.9em;

    &.main-content {
      &--active {
        width: calc(100% - 5em);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.page__main-content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100% - 20em);
  margin-left: 10.9em;
}
.page__main-content.main-content--active {
  width: calc(100% - 5em);
}
```

You basically need to say `.page__main-content` WITH another class `.main-content`

Here's the fiddle to show it working:
https://jsfiddle.net/nbqfjcwh/

Also, your React compiler should be compiling the `className` to `class` - which is why I think you're not seeing the results.

Comment: Are you sure? What does yours compile to? Paste the SASS I wrote into https://www.sassmeister.com/. It comples to what I have, which would target your element with `page__main-content main-content--active` as classes.

Comment: More reading on the CSS module - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212843/css-classname-not-reflecting-when-using-css-modules-in-my-react-component

Comment: Did a lot of debugging, my bracket was in the wrong place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In yous Sass example, your target poins to `.page__main-content--active`

```
.page{
  &__main-content{
    &--active {     <-- this means `.page__main-content--active`
      width: calc(100% - 5em);
    }
  }
}
```

However, your class name is `main-content--active`. That is why it does not work.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Call your node `<div className="page__main-content active">`
   And target your styles like this:

```
  .page{
      &__main-content{
          &.active {
              width: calc(100% - 5em);
          }
      }
  }
```

2. Call your node `<div className="page__main-content page__main-content--active">`
   And target your styles like this:

```
  .page{
      &__main-content{
          &--active {
              width: calc(100% - 5em);
          }
      }
  }
```

Hope it helps.